Why is Linux mutex_waiter struct created on the kernel stack?
I examined the Linux mutex implementation code, where if the lock is held by others, the lock function creates a mutex_waiter struct on the stack (as a local variable) and adds this struct as a node into the wait_list of the mutex. The calling process then goes to sleep and is only awakened later when its previous waiter releases the lock and assigns it the ownership.
However, I'm confused about where exactly this mutex_waiter node gets created - specifically, on the kernel stack of the calling process. I'm uncertain whether kernel stacks are shared across different processes. So, I'm wondering how the system chains all nodes created in each process's stacks (in different virtual address spaces). Are all kernel stacks shared, perhaps allocated on the kernel heap?
I attempted to delve into the source code for clarification, but I'm stuck due to the complexity and depth of encapsulation levels.

"I'm uncertain whether kernel stacks are shared across different processes." - There's only a single kernel address space when executing in kernel mode, unlike the (virtual) address space for each user process. As long as the stack frame exists, the (kernel) memory allocated to a local variable is valid storage, and accessible by any kernel routine. "Are all kernel stacks shared" - Since there's only a single kernel address space, there's no actual exclusion mechanism, so in a sense they're "shared".

Some info in Kernel Stacks for x86, but the part about kernel stacks for active threads applies to other arches too.
